# Construct q command to get metadata for all tables

Tags: kdb

I'd like to construct a query to retrieve table metadata for each table.

I can get metadata for a single table with the `meta` function. I can chain that with `` tables \`. ``, which returns all of the tables in the `.` namespace, to construct `` (meta')tables `. ``.

This is almost what I want as it returns a list of metadata tables. The problem is that I dont know what metadata table belongs to which kdb table.

Ideally, I could construct a query which returns a table where each row is tablename + results of `meta tablename`. Any advice for constructing such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q)trade:([] sym: 10?`4; time:10?.z.t; prx:10?100f; sz:10?10000);
q)quote:([] sym: 10?`4; time:10?.z.t; bPrx:10?100f; aPrx:10?100f; bSz:10?10000; aSz:10?10000);
q)testTable:update `s#a from ([] a:til 10; b: 10?`3; c:10?.z.p);
q)raze {update table:x from 0!meta x}'[tables[]]
    c    t f a table
    --------------------
    sym  s     quote
    time t     quote
    bPrx f     quote
    aPrx f     quote
    bSz  j     quote
    aSz  j     quote
    a    j   s testTable
    b    s     testTable
    c    p     testTable
    sym  s     trade
    time t     trade
    prx  f     trade
    sz   j     trade
```

> I could construct a query which returns a table where each row is tablename + results of "meta tablename". Any advice for constructing such a query?

If you did want to do it in this manner, there are many ways. One example:

```````
q)update tableMeta:meta'[table] from ([] table:tables[])
    table     tableMeta
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    quote     (+(,`c)!,`sym`time`bPrx`aPrx`bSz`aSz)!+`t`f`a!("stffjj";``````;``````)
    testTable (+(,`c)!,`a`b`c)!+`t`f`a!("jsp";```;`s``)
    trade     (+(,`c)!,`sym`time`prx`sz)!+`t`f`a!("stfj";````;````)
```````

Comment: Thank you, the first is a good solution, but the second is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: My understanding of the update command here is that it is returning the table returned by "tables[]" with an additional tableMeta column that is generated by calling meta on the "table" column. Do I have it right?